# Deleting table in sqlite including column names

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a problem deleting tables in SqLite.

If I use-

db.delete(TABLE_NAME, null, null);

The contents of the table are deleted but the column names still remain. How do I delete the column names as well?

I have also tried db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME+"Name of the table");

But it does not work at all.

How do I delete the entire table programmatically or is there any way to delete the entire database without rooting the phone( else we get "Permission denied" errors) through code?

Here is a part of the code dealing with onCreate, creating and deleting the tables.

```
package com.example.appchecker;



import java.io.File;

import com.example.appchecker.FeedReaderContract.CycDetails;
import com.example.appchecker.FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class FeedReaderDbHelper2 extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    // If you change the database schema, you must increment the database version.
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "final31.db";
    public static boolean exists = false;
private static final String TEXT_TYPE = " TEXT";
private static final String COMMA_SEP = ", ";
private static final String SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES =
    " CREATE TABLE " +FeedEntry.TABLE_NAME + " (" +
    FeedEntry._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY" + COMMA_SEP +
    FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_NUMBER + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
    FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_APP_NAME + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
    FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_PKG_NAME + TEXT_TYPE + 
    // Any other options for the CREATE command
    ");";

private static final String SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES2 =
        " CREATE TABLE " +CycDetails.TABLE_NAME + " (" +
        CycDetails._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY" + COMMA_SEP +
         CycDetails.COLUMN_NAME_CYCLENAME + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
        CycDetails.COLUMN_NAME_DATE + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
       CycDetails.COLUMN_NAME_OSVERSION + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
        CycDetails.COLUMN_NAME_SWVERSION + TEXT_TYPE + 
        // Any other options for the CREATE command
        ");";



private static final String SQL_DELETE_ENTRIES1 =
    "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " +   DATABASE_NAME.substring(0,DATABASE_NAME.length()-3)+".Mobile_App_Details";
private static final String SQL_DELETE_ENTRIES2 =
        "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_NAME.substring(0, DATABASE_NAME.length()-3)+".Cycle_Details";

public FeedReaderDbHelper2(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {




         db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES);
         db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES2);
         return;

 } /*Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select DISTINCT tbl_name from sqlite_master where tbl_name = '"+FeedEntry.TABLE_NAME+"'", null);
    System.out.println("In on create1") ;
if(cursor==null)
{
        System.out.println("In on create")  ;
        db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES);

    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Update phase")  ;
        exists=true;
    }
  */
   }

public static void deletetable(SQLiteDatabase db)
{



    db.delete(FeedEntry.TABLE_NAME, null, null);
    db.delete(CycDetails.TABLE_NAME, null, null);
    db.execSQL(SQL_DELETE_ENTRIES1);
     db.execSQL(SQL_DELETE_ENTRIES2);

}

public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // This database is only a cache for online data, so its upgrade policy is
    // to simply to discard the data and start over
    //System.out.println("Update phase")    ;
    db.execSQL(SQL_DELETE_ENTRIES1);
 db.execSQL(SQL_DELETE_ENTRIES2);
    //db.delete(FeedEntry.TABLE_NAME, null, null);
    onCreate(db);
}
public void onDowngrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    onUpgrade(db, oldVersion, newVersion);
}
}
```

Currently I am instantiating the function deletetable in an on_click even in the MainActicity. Logcat shows no errors but when I print the retrieved column names, it prints some of the column names whose entries have already been deleted. I do not want those columns.

And I am not using the upgrade method in any way.

Answer (score 1):

You should correct your syntax of drop table SQL ( DROP TABLE IF EXISTS is twice ), there's no reason for which it doesn't work.

If you get permission denied error then make sure you are accessing the database of your own app , not another app's database. Double check you have used correct package name if needed when you have created your database.

Comment: sorry that was a typo. I have edited my Question. The problem is not with that.

Comment: show some codes that you used to create your database and logcat when you get error as well.

Answer (score 0):

remove table from database.

db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + YOUR_TABLE);

Comment: Like I said, that is not deleting the entire table. If I have kept the table in a database, should I access it using dot operator? that is      db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_NAME + "." +YOUR_TABLE);

Answer (score 0):

To drop a table, just use the [DROP TABLE](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_droptable.html) statement.

The table name should be *exactly* the same that you used in the `CREATE TABLE` statement.
In your case, this would be:

```java
SQL_DELETE_ENTRIES1 = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + FeedEntry.TABLE_NAME;
SQL_DELETE_ENTRIES2 = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + CycDetails.TABLE_NAME;
```